# Find a port in a configuration file with regex

Tags: regex, bash

in a configuration file (nginx default.conf) I got some strings like this:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name sudomain1.somewhere.com ;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain1.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8999/;
                }
}
```

In a bash script, I would like to catch the port number "***8999***" in a variable to use it just after in the script.

If possible using the entire string above.

Because in that file I have several times this sequence, and the only variable mark I is the "***subdomain1***"

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What about `var=$(cat default.conf | grep ":[0-9]+\/")`?

Comment: `the only variable mark I is the "subdomain1"`, unclear for me..

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help, but I need to find it related to subdomain1

Comment: I have a lot of sequences like this, for example  subdomain1 have a proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8999, subdomain2 -> http://127.0.0.1:8154,  subdomain3 -> http://127.0.0.1:????, etc...

Comment: please edit your question to include a small set of data and the expected output from that data. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Shelter for the tip, I'll do better the next time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the single line:

```
( ln=$(grep -A 1 sudomain1 nginxconf.txt | tail -n1); port=${ln##*:}; port=${port%/*}; echo "port: $port" )
```

or as a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ln=$(grep -A 1 sudomain1 nginxconf.txt | tail -n1)

port=${ln##*:}
port=${port%/*}

echo "port: $port"
```

You first locate `sudomain1` and the line that follows with using `grep -A 1` then use `tail -n` to keep only the last line. Then it is simple **parameter matching/substring extraction** to isolate `8999`.

**output**

```
port: 8999
```

**Note:** you spell `subdomain1` as `sudomain1` in your conf file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
port="$(grep -A 1 'proxy_set_header.*sudomain1\.' file | grep -Po ':\K[0-9]+(?=/)')"
echo $port
```

Output:

```
8999
```

Comment: It works fine ! sorry, I gave validation to David C. Rankin because he's solution works as well but is easier to integrate into my script. Thank you for your support and understanding !